# Can Intelligencia UrlRewriter.NET handle unicode in querystring?

Tags: asp.net, unicode, urlrewriter.net

I have been using UrlRewriter.NET to perform some rewrites. Which was working OK for english texts, but for Unicode data it shows "???????"

So, is there any way I can make it work with unicode, too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can support. Use ENCODE. Tested on 2.0.0.9 version, from https://github.com/sethyates/urlrewriter

```
<rewrite url="/test.aspx/(.*)/$" to="/test.aspx?bla=${encode($1)}" processing="stop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly out of the box, I just ran a quick test using some Arabic characters and it seems to work correctly. A few things to check:

- Ensure that your XML configuration is being read correctly and has a root declaration of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`
- Check to see if your page is setting the response encoding correctly (for example, UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1)

If nothing else, can you post an example of this case which is rendering incorrectly?